# Как правильно сериализовать данные из mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Есть сервис который сохраняет в монгу user

```
create(createUserDto: UserCreateDto): Promise<User> {
const userCreated = new this.userModel(createUserDto);

return userCreated.save();
}
```

после чего возвращает то, что сохранил.
Вот я это логирую, все ок:

```
{
  image: 'test6',
  bio: 'test6',
  lastname: 'test6',
  _id: 5f5db0b24167bf636c370798,
  name: 'test6',
  email: 'test6@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$K3YLR3GxYUofLBXWrSV96O40eGE7ERak3OnFU6T.Tpl1djEp3qEB2'
}
```

Я хочу сериализировать юзера, что бы не бы пароля не было в этом объекте, делаю вот так:

```
const { password, ...userCreatedSerialized } = userCreated;
```

и возвращаю уже **userCreatedSerialized**. Но, в **userCreatedSerialized** уже огромный объект

```
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: undefined,
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: undefined,
    saving: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 5f5db16bc352c652acdf4138,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    cachedRequired: {},
    session: null,
    '$setCalled': Set { 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'bio', 'image', 'password' },
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    '$options': { defaults: true }
  },
  isNew: true,
  errors: undefined,
  '$locals': {},
  '$op': null,
  _doc: {
    image: 'test6',
    bio: 'test6',
    lastname: 'test6',
    _id: 5f5db16bc352c652acdf4138,
    name: 'test6',
    email: 'test6@gmail.com',
    password: '$2b$10$UiuihpGO0V0n7/730wB5q.5VfuqUGNcAjPLdTrwuKeNrx6VAbm/0u'
  }
}
```

В котором есть и вложенный объект **_doc**, который и есть мой юзер. Я не пойму почему после рест операции у меня объект совершенно другой....откуда там берутся все эти поля? Если исходный объект, который я деструктурирую выглядит совершенно иначе....
И как правильно делать сериализацию в таком случае?
Ну то есть я могу сделать как-то так

```
{ _doc: { password, ...userSerialized } } = userCreated;
```

Хотя typescript мне не позволяет сделать такое...потому что в модели User нет никакого поля _doc
И все же откуда берется тьма этих полей после реста, ведь их нет в логе  **userCreated**

Comment: `const { password, ...userCreatedSerialized } = userCreated.toObect()`

Comment: Спасибо, решило проблему. Но откуда такое поведение берется я так и не понял=)

Comment: Это потому что модель в mongoose — это весьма сложный объект с кучей наследованных служебных полей, сеттерами и геттерами... Когда Вы его таким образом деструктурируете, все эти поля и попадают в Ваш объект. А вот методы `toString()`, `toObject()` и `toJSON()` определены там так, что возвращают (по умолчанию) только поля, непосредственно заданные в схеме документа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я это понимаю, что объект сложный и много полей, но почему когда я его логирую, до рест операции, вот просто ответ userCreated - я получаю обычный объект который описание схеме, а эти все служебные поля появляются только после того как я этот userCreated деструктурирую. Ну то есть это какая-то квантовая механика

Comment: А вы загляните в `userCreated.__proto__` :Я не случайно упомянул наследование. :)

Comment: Ну хорошо, если я создам объект 
`const obj = {name: 'john', lastname: 'Doe'}`
еще и допустим создам свойство в его прототипе:
`obj.__proto__.myptotofield = "hidden"`
Затем я деструктурирую объект:
`const {name, ...rest} = obj;`
То в **rest** будет только 
`{lastname: "Doe"}`

А у нас что получается - я логирую объект **userCreated**
в нем шесть свойств описаных в схеме. Я деструктурирую это объект
`const { password, ...userCreatedSerialized } = userCreated`

Comment: И получаю, что в **password** лежит значение поля **password**  из исходного объекта - все верно. Но в **userCreatedSerialized** появился целый ворох свойст, просто из-за реста, до этого там этого ничего не было, я же не делал ничего с прототипом, почему свойствам из прототипа бы появится в ресте?